# Running a python file from a file multiple times

Tags: python, list, class, pygame, instance

Basically I am making a Tower Defense game and I have a python file called enemy.py which has the round inside and I have a file called main.py which is the end of round screen. I want main.py to execute enemy.py after every round is finished but it gives me a error on the second time. I am using the import function to open the other files. In addition can someone help me make it so the error is not so big I am so confused!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\ICT\A level\Computing\Tower Defense Code\main.py", line 62, in <module>
    createMenu()
  File "H:\ICT\A level\Computing\Tower Defense Code\main.py", line 9, in     createMenu
    newRound()
  File "H:\ICT\A level\Computing\Tower Defense Code\main.py", line 23, in     newRound
    cancelLoop()
  File "H:\ICT\A level\Computing\Tower Defense Code\main.py", line 38, in     cancelLoop
    startRound()
  File "H:\ICT\A level\Computing\Tower Defense Code\main.py", line 41, in     startRound
    import enemy.py
  File "H:\ICT\A level\Computing\Tower Defense Code\enemy.py", line 107, in     <module>
    enemy.draw(screen)
  File "H:\ICT\A level\Computing\Tower Defense Code\enemy.py", line 35, in     draw
    life(self)
  File "H:\ICT\A level\Computing\Tower Defense Code\enemy.py", line 55, in     life
    import main.py
  File "H:\ICT\A level\Computing\Tower Defense Code\main.py", line 62, in     <module>
    createMenu()
  File "H:\ICT\A level\Computing\Tower Defense Code\main.py", line 9, in     createMenu
    newRound()
  File "H:\ICT\A level\Computing\Tower Defense Code\main.py", line 23, in     newRound
    cancelLoop()
  File "H:\ICT\A level\Computing\Tower Defense Code\main.py", line 38, in     cancelLoop
    startRound()
  File "H:\ICT\A level\Computing\Tower Defense Code\main.py", line 41, in    startRound
    import enemy.py
ImportError: No module named 'enemy.py'; 'enemy' is not a package
```

> > > 

Comment: Please show minimal working / failing sample code - looks like it would be helpful also,  looking up how python imports only on first time ...

Comment: You only have to import it once.  You type `import enemy` not `import enemy.py`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First drop the .py file suffix. The syntax is just:

```
import enemy
```

This will run all the code in enemy.py (presuming enemy.py is located in a path known to Python).

If you'd like to repeat this process, the command to use is:

```
reload(enemy)
```

This is not a great way to use a module though. You're better off creating a function inside enemy and calling it directly:

```
import enemy
enemy.enemy()
```

Comment: Thank you very much this is so helpful